# MySQL randomly losing results

Tags: mysql, sql

I've encountered a bug in my code, where mysql query didn't return results. So, I've set up mysql slow log to fetch all queries. When everything is fine, I get:

```
# User@Host: SAMP_1[SAMP_1] @ localhost []
# Query_time: 0.000061  Lock_time: 0.000000 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 0
SET timestamp=1392563921;
SELECT * FROM (SELECT 0 AS mark, ua.id AS id, ua.uid AS uid, ua.offset AS colThird, ua.value AS colFourth, NULL AS colFifth FROM `user_achievements` ua UNION ALL SELECT 1, uiw.* FROM `user_inv_weapons` uiw UNION ALL SELECT 2, ul.*, NULL FROM `user_licenses` ul UNION ALL SELECT 3, un.*, NULL FROM `user_notes` un    UNION ALL SELECT 4, ups.*, NULL FROM `user_punishments` ups UNION ALL SELECT 5, us.*, NULL FROM `user_skills` us UNION ALL SELECT 6, uw.* FROM `user_weapons` uw UNION ALL SELECT 7, upk.*, NULL FROM `user_perks` upk ) AS uqq WHERE uqq.uid = 1 ORDER BY mark ASC, id ASC;
# User@Host: SAMP_1[SAMP_1] @ localhost []
# Query_time: 0.000502  Lock_time: 0.000128 Rows_sent: 2  Rows_examined: 11
SET timestamp=1392563922;
SELECT * FROM vehicles WHERE owner = 'Foo_Bar' ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 0, 2;
```

Take a look at second rows_sent - it's 2, and that's the correct number of results. However, sometimes, exact same query returns nothing, when query before it takes much longer:

```
# Time: 140216 15:35:36
# User@Host: SAMP_1[SAMP_1] @ localhost []
# Query_time: 2.778103  Lock_time: 0.000504 Rows_sent: 84  Rows_examined: 507332
SET timestamp=1392561336;
SELECT * FROM (SELECT 0 AS mark, ua.id AS id, ua.uid AS uid, ua.offset AS colThird, ua.value AS colFourth, NULL AS colFifth FROM `user_achievements` ua UNION ALL SELECT 1, uiw.* FROM `user_inv_weapons` uiw UNION ALL SELECT 2, ul.*, NULL FROM `user_licenses` ul UNION ALL SELECT 3, un.*, NULL FROM `user_notes` un    UNION ALL SELECT 4, ups.*, NULL FROM `user_punishments` ups UNION ALL SELECT 5, us.*, NULL FROM `user_skills` us UNION ALL SELECT 6, uw.* FROM `user_weapons` uw UNION ALL SELECT 7, upk.*, NULL FROM `user_perks` upk ) AS uqq WHERE uqq.uid = 1 ORDER BY mark ASC, id ASC;
# User@Host: SAMP_1[SAMP_1] @ localhost []
# Query_time: 0.000504  Lock_time: 0.000139 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 11
SET timestamp=1392561336;
SELECT * FROM vehicles WHERE owner = 'Foo_Bar' ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 0, 2;
```

What is happening? What can I examine further to get the reason behind lack of result and/or long query execution time? Thank you.

Comment: Are these the real queries you are using?  I find it hard to believe that all those tables have the same columns.  Also, what does `timestamp` have to do with it?

Comment: Actual queries. "Set timestamp" is all over the slow log, not once executed directly by me though. http://pastebin.com/hg7vadzw - that's the table structure (I was forced to match the current infrastructure, so ugly in many places).

Comment: Try analyzing the table one, time for query might be because of improper usage of index, But I dont think you outputs can differ  though

Comment: And try revisiting your query if this is inside some script. 
- Union and SELECT * are not advisable, any table having a column change can screw up things. Use exact column names
-  SELECT * from (SELECT.. ) derived queries is quite often not efficient with indexes,

Comment: I'm gonna break down the first query into smaller ones without any additional magic (Explain for first one http://jsfiddle.net/yyQ62/ ). Is it possible the query is so terrible, it corrupts results of the following query?